# Access JS object with a key

Tags: javascript

I can access a value like `driver.my_friends["793659690"].name` but now I am using it in a loop where `key` will hold the key.

`driver.my_friends[key].name` doesn't work. Says undefined, and `driver.my_friends["key"].name` will look for a key named key. So how do I use it so that the variable of the variable is evaluated too.

Comment: `driver.my_friends[key].name` should work, so most likely whatever `key` you're iterating through doesn't exist.  Try debugging other data yourself or providing more of the surrounding code.

Comment: `driver.my_friends[key].name` is correct.  My guess is that `key` is set to the wrong value. [See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N7ys3/) for a working example.

Comment: @mVChr @lonesomeday Thanks! You were right, logic error X(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.my_friends[key].name` is the right way. It is possible that no key like `key` exists in `driver.my_friends` =) and/or that `.name` doesn't exist in that object.

You can debug that very easily:

```
console.log(driver.my_friends[key]);
console.log(driver.my_friends[key].name);
```

Even IE8 has a console like that.

Comment: Thanks! The key didn't existed as in that loop my key was in value and key were very small numbers.

Answer (score 1):

when you're iterating over an object's properties, some "garbage" may get into "key" variable. I would suggest the following:

```
for (var key in driver.my_friends) {
  if (key && driver.my_friends[key] && driver.my_friends[key].name) {
    // Do what you need here
  }
}
```

Also, make sure that when the value of driver.my_friends[key] gets set, the key is the same as the one used for reading it